# Understanding Pointer Arithmetic of Array Declared in C

Tags: java, c, arrays

I am trying to convert some `C` code into another language (eg: Java or C#). The problem is understanding a few things about how these arrays are being declared and used...

This is the minimum code that demonstrates my issue:

```
static void some_function ( )
{
    int16_t arr_tmpShort[120 + 40], *ptr0, *ptr1;
    int offset = 5;
    
    //assume that "arr_tmpShort" is now filled with some values
    ptr0 = arr_tmpShort + 84 - offset;
    ptr1 = arr_tmpShort + 85;

}
```

So I need a second opinion:

This line:

```
int16_t arr_tmpShort[120 + 40];
```

is creating an array for holding **160** entries of Shorts. That `plus` sign is doing nothing special except simple arithmetic, right?

**Problem:** Now these lines

```
    ptr0 = arr_tmpShort + 84 - offset;
    ptr1 = arr_tmpShort + 85;
```

are strange cos I'm seeing arithmetic on an array.
This is new to me and after some research I need clarification on which of the below is more valid or true...

- `ptr0 = arr_tmpShort + 84` is equal to Java/C# as `arr_tmpShort[84]` (a position in array)?
- Is it considered as `ptr0 =`

  - either `(arr_tmpShort[84] - offset); //get [84] Short value and minus it by offset`?
  - or `(arr_tmpShort[84 - offset]); //get [84 - offset] Short value from array`?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think that `ptr0 = arr_tmpShort + 84 - offset;` is getting the 84th element, minus the offset (`5`), so that would be the 79th element

Comment: `ptr0` contains the address of the element at index 79, which is not the same as the value of the element at index 79. `arr_tmpShort[79]` would be the value of the element at index 79. Answer to (1) is "yes".

Comment: Java doesn't have pointers, it has references, and you can't do arithmetic on references in Java like you can with pointers in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C pointer arithmetic: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_arithmetic.htm

> ptr0 = arr_tmpShort + 84 is equal to Java/C# as arr_tmpShort[84] (a position in array)?

No.  It calculates the address needed, but doesn't actually access a value (either read or write).

> Is it considered as ptr0 =
>       or (arr_tmpShort[84 - offset]); //get [84 - offset] Short value from array?

It's closest to this one, but again there's no access of the element.  The address of `arr_tmpShort[84-offset]` is caculated, but no access is done yet.

To access the element, you typically have to derefernce the variable.

```
ptr0 = arr_tmpShort + 84;
short x = *ptr0;     // this retrieves the 84th element, assuming a short
```

Comment: Thanks. I've had a chance to check things and your Answer helps best.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, most likely that will be optimized out to 160 by the compiler.

2) In c, you can think of arrays and pointers as being the same thing.
So, when you have code like `i[3]` this would be equivalent to writing `*(i+3)`. Both of these return the value of the element stored in the 3rd memory location after the start of the array i. [More information on pointers can be found here](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html)

So `ptr0 = arr_tmpShort + 84 - offset` is going to be equal to the memory location of `arr_tmpShort[84 - offset]` which in this case is `arr_tmpShort[79]`.

Later you could also write `*ptr0` and if no other modifications are made, it would be equal to `arr_tmpShort[79]`.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me understand the C side of things like `*ptr0` referencing... In Java I was going to just set the Array value into some Short var.